# CSV error when loading file into 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I have a CSV file and my assignment involves taking that file and loading it into a 2D array. I've counted how many rows there and how man columns there are but, when I go to load it into the array I get the error

> "non-static variable filetable cannot be referenced from a static
>   context"

But when if I do this `public static String[][] filetable = new String[rows][cols];`

I get the error

> Illegal reference forward Usage of static non-final variable during
>   intialization

Code:

```
public String[][] filetable = new String[rows][cols];//The second error doesn't show up here since I haven't put 'static' after public.
public static int rows = 0;
public static int cols = 0;

 public static void to_Array(File example)
{        


 try 
    {
         FileReader file = new FileReader(example);
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);  

         if(sc.hasNextLine())
         { 
             String[] tokens = sc.nextLine().split(",");
             cols = tokens.length;
             rows++;
         }

         while(sc.hasNextLine())
         {
             rows++;
             sc.nextLine();                 
         }

         //Probably not the right way to load the file into the array, but will fix it later
         for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
         {
             for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
             {
                 filetable[r][c] = sc.next();// This where the first error shows up
             }
         }


    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: Why not just make `to_Array` an instance method?

Comment: "non-static variable filetable cannot be referenced from a static context" there's your clue

Comment: @Joe, I'm sorry but, what is an instance method?

Comment: @johnll I assume the error suggests that filetable is non-static which is why I changed it into public static String[][] filetable = new String[rows][cols]; but then I get the second error(stated above) for the line. ;A;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void  method
```

if the method is static you can reference to the local variable only if they are also static

```
public SomeClass {
  private static String var1;
  private String var2;

  public void someMethod(){
     this.var2 // is allowed 
     this.var1 // is allowed
   }

   public static void someMethod(){
     this.var2 // is allowed 
     this.var1 // is not allowed
   }



}
```

i suggest that you create a method in the class than in the main() method create a new instance of the class than call the method

```
 SomeClass test = new SomeClass():
  test.someMethod()// copy the code of the main to this method
```